# UIView growth animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a small horizontal bar, that goes from one side to another side of the device.
When user tap this bar, i want to make her grow to up. All test that i did the bar grows downward, or when i changed the origin.y and the size.height the bar goes too fast to new y position and then grows to bottom on right position. i can not make a smooth growing animation to up.

Example code:

```
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

int sizeToGrow = 100;
CGRect barFrame = CGRectMake(weakSelf.frame.origin.x, 
                             weakSelf.frame.origin.y - sizeToGrow, 
                             weakSelf.frame.size.width, 
                             weakSelf.frame.size.height + sizeToGrow);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     weakSelf.frame = barFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

Comment: Did you try `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` instead?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried all animation options =S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making the duration longer it should make the animation more gradual.

Try a value of around `2.0f` seconds.

Try it without options, that way the animation will be linear:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                      delay:0
                    options:0
                 animations:^{
                     weakSelf.frame = barFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

Comment: I tried that. But that code above with 2 seconds makes the bar grows fast downward and then slowly moves upwards. Very strange that behaviour.

Comment: It worked, thanks.. i realized too that the real problem is in my layoutSubviews method that grows a gradient layer together,this bug happens on gradient layer and not in the UIView